# How to do JMS performance testing with JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jms, performance-testing

I'm using `@JmsListener` annotation to fetch logs from Azure service bus queue and later saving it into Elasticsearch.

I need to conduct performance testing using JMeter. There's no http endpoint. I'm just using `@JmsListener` annotation as soon as application starts it auto fetch all data from bus. Can someone guide on this?

I get to know there's a JMS subscriber and JMS point-to-point sampler option in JMeter, but what all parameters do I need to set? There's one initial context factory parameter. I provided it as `org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.InitialContextFactory`, and it's giving below error.

```
Response message:javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory]
```

I'm using below dependency in my code.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms</artifactId>
   <version>5.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone help on this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the `javax.naming.NoInitialContextException` you need to put the jar containing `org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.InitialContextFactory` on JMeter's classpath. For example, you can just drop it into the `JMETER_HOME/lib` directory. See [the documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Libraries for ActiveMQ JMS](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#libraries_activemq) which states:

> You will need to add the jar `activemq-all-X.X.X.jar` to your classpath, e.g. by storing it in the `lib/` directory.
>
> See [ActiveMQ initial configuration page](https://activemq.apache.org/initial-configuration.html) for details.

Check out the following materials:

- [Building a JMS Topic Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html)
- [Building a JMS Point-to-Point Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html)

If you prefer Java code you can also consider [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) instead.

Comment: For what it's worth, the OP isn't using ActiveMQ. He's using the Apache Qpid JMS client. It uses the AMQP protocol which is supported by Azure Service Bus.